# How to add multiple Views to UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, addsubview

I have a ScrollView (contentScrollView) which should later contain 20 pages with a UIViewController for each page.

Now this is what I get when adding the UIViewControllers view to the contentScrollView (the Button in the upper right corner is from the MainViewController so it doesn't affect the problem)
[image: gray bar at the top ?!]

and I got this code in my **MainViewController** class where my contentScrollView is in:

```
 Slide1ViewController*test = [[Slide1ViewController alloc] init];
test.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
[self.contentScrollView addSubview:[test view]];
```

when I add a background like this right after setting the frame:

```
test.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

then I get the black background without that Bar on the top but the Label which is in the Slide1ViewController.xib won't appear.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: try `[contentScrollView addSubview:test.view]`; and do make sure the content size of scrollview matches the frame of the Test Class

Comment: Thank you for your answer I just changed to your code but it didn't help still got the navBar

Comment: You need to add **view**'s to the scrollView, **not view controller**'s....

Comment: but i did so ? i added test.view ->test is the UIViewController and view is its view

Answer (score 0):

If you really need 20 pages beaing each one a view controller you should use a uinavigationcontroller and if you really wanna have a scroll view, use a uitableview and make each cell the view of one of your uiviewcontroller because that way the each view will be loaded when needed, whereas in a scroll view you might get too much contend loaded at the same time.

Comment: but i need it horizontal for sliding like pages is that possible with a tableview too ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i didn't realize UINavigationController was still selected so that i created the class while believing it's a UIViewController